# Typehint for sequelize model using JsDoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to add typehints using JsDoc annotations for VS code and running into an issue with VS code complaining about the `return user;` line. The codebase is javascript and I have a typescript file to write the typehints in.

user.js:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} userID
 * @returns {Promise<UserModel>}
 */
const getByID = async (userID) => {
  const user = await User.findByPk(userID);

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("not found");
  }

  // Warning from VS code:
  // Type 'Model<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserModel': id, first_name, last_name
  return user;
};
```

globals.d.ts:

```js
import { Model } from "sequelize";

interface UserAttributes {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}

export interface UserModel extends Model<UserAttributes>, UserAttributes {}
```

Can someone please suggest how I best write the `UserModel` interface so that VS code does not throw a warning?